# Destroying custom object within useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

There is a basic vanilla js component that should be executed when element is added to DOM (componentDidMount) and destroyed when removed. Here is a basic example of such component:

```
class TestComponent {
  interval?: number;
    constructor() {
    this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        console.log('interval is ticking')
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  destroy() {
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```

I add it via React like so:

```
function TestApp() {
  const [testComponent, setTestComponent] = React.useState<TestComponent|null>(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // initialize component when it's added to dom
    const localTestComponent = new TestComponent();
    setTestComponent(localTestComponent);
    
    return () => {
      // destroy component when it's removed
      if (testComponent) {
        testComponent.destroy();
      }
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>Test app</div>
  );
}
```

For some reason it initializes twice, but never destroys (I can tell because "interval is ticking" message appears twice each second, but it should tick only once per second). Any idea why this is happening?

The `destroy()` method is never reached because `if (testComponent) {` is `null` in the cleanup phase.

I tried placing this component at the very root of my app and removing all third-party code, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Try and maintain a class field to check whether the component has already been destroyed or not.

Comment: Usually you should only store data in state; also fyi https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava ty, what's a better way to store such object (TestComponent object in this case) if not in state?

Comment: @Marvin3 if you need to store it check `useRef`

Comment: For your destroy -> `if (testComponent) {`  -> `if (localTestComponent) {`   `testComponent` won't exist inside your `useEffect`.   Also as pointed out don't store this in `state`, a `useRef` would be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everything should be state.

When you call `setTestComponent(localTestComponent)`, it requires a rerender in order to change the value of `testComponent`. In your effect `testComponent` is still `null`. You already have the value in `localTestComponent`, just use it instead of `testComponent`. You don't need state for that

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const localTestComponent = new TestComponent();
    
    return localTestComponent.destroy
}, []);
```

Comment: ty, the problem is I need to pass this "TestComponent" further down the tree (it's actually passed to context provider), so I cant keep it fully local like that.

Comment: Sure, use a state for that, but inside the effect don't use the state, use the variable localTestComponent

Comment: oooh, I'll try that, thanks again